# how to Read .txt file on new activity when i click textview

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to read a .txt file on new activity (for example "secondactivity.tk"). When I click Textview, I succefully read text, but just in the same Activity.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.coding

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.io.IOException

class Dusterlist : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dacialist)
        var string = ""
        var myoutput = string
        val txtsh1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtsh1)
        val txt7 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView7);
        txt7.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            try {
                val inputStream = assets.open("mytextfile.txt")
                val size: Int = inputStream.available()
                val buffer = ByteArray(size)
                inputStream.read(buffer).toString()
                string = String(buffer)
                var txtdetail = String(buffer)
                txtsh1.text = txtdetail

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                }


        } )}

    }
```

So, please, what should I add in the mainactivity and secondactivity?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the code above is ok, but i want to, when i click on txt7, can read .txt and show that .txt in secondactivity

Comment: If you're saying you want to click a thing in ActivityA and then open ActivityB and display the text, you'll need to pass some data to ActivityB through the `Intent` you use to open it. E.g. pass the filename (`"mytextfile.txt"`) and then use the same code up there to open the file and get the text for display: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles#sdba

Comment: Yes, but how i do that, im new to coding

Comment: @cactustictacs And one more thing, in ActivityA, i have many Textview, so if i click on any one, he can shiw specific "textfile.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the contents of your text file in a textview in another activity you have to pass it through Intent.
Here is your code after clicking on the txt7:

```
txt7.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    try {
        val inputStream = assets.open("mytextfile.txt")
        val size: Int = inputStream.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        inputStream.read(buffer).toString()
        string = String(buffer)
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("textfile", string)
        startActivity(intent)

    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
})
```

And in the SecondActivity:

```
val textfile = intent.getStringExtra("textfile")

val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
textView.text = textfile
```